# error in R while installing packages: problems with shiny or java_home? is it due to opensteetmap?

Tags: r, shiny, openstreetmap

I'm new with R unfortunately, but i need it to open a specific file which should be a graphical user interface. 
After the source command:

```r
source("D:\\R\\win-library\\3.5\\muxViz-master\\muxVizGUI.R")
```

I'm facing this error:

```
"Installing package into ‘D:/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Warning: package ‘shiny’ is in use and will not be installed

Carico il pacchetto richiesto: OpenStreetMap

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘OpenStreetMap’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:

  call: fun(libname, pkgname)

  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry

Installing package into ‘D:/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

provo con l'URL 'https://cran.stat.unipd.it/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/OpenStreetMap_0.3.3.zip'

Content type 'application/zip' length 2264648 bytes (2.2 MB)
downloaded 2.2 MB

package ‘OpenStreetMap’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked


The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\Camla\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpE9NQB2\downloaded_packages
```

> Error in shinyAppDir(x) : App dir must contain either app.R or server.R.".

The contents of this directory come from http://github.com/manlius/muxViz.

Please help.

Comment: Can you please include the code that you ran that generated the error?

Comment: yes, it is just: source("D:\\R\\win-library\\3.5\\muxViz-master\\muxVizGUI.R")

Comment: Can you post the contents of that file?

Comment: https://github.com/manlius/muxViz   these are the files I downloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of `muxVizGUI.R` is `runApp(getwd())`. It expects that your working directory is the same directory in which the `ui.R` and `server.R` files are located. You should change to that directory before sourcing the file:

```r
setwd("D:\\R\\win-library\\3.5\\muxViz-master")
source("muxVizGUI.R")
```

Comment: oooh thank you!! it works! I would never been able to understand it by myself! thank you very much...